# How do I prevent UITabBarController from updating subviews?

Tags: ios, swift

Inside of a ContainerView, I have a UITabBarController subclass where I have modified the UITabBar Y Position. Instead of it being on the bottom, I have moved it closer to the top using this code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    delegate = self
    selectedViewController?.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.size.height)
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    selectedViewController?.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tabBar.frame.size.height)
}
```

It works great initially: the first tab view contains a UITableView, and it seems to adjust its frame for the new position of the UITabBar. However, if I push a ViewController on the stack, halfway through the push animation, the bottom of the view containing the UITableView jumps up like the UITabBar is still there. So, a portion of the top of the view ends up behind the UITabBar and upon popping this new ViewController off the stack, back to the UITabBarController, the view(with the tableView) remains in this position behind the new position of the tabBar. I've tried changing the view origin in ViewWillAppear, ViewWillDisappear, ViewDidDisappear, and none of these methods were able to reset the position of the view(containing the tableView) to beneath the new location of the UITabBar.

I'm not sure what's causing this to happen, or what lifecycle method to investigate.

Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT: The TableView is the one actually changing it's Origin, NOT the view.

Comment: @Sh_Khan unfortunately I tried that as well, and it causes the same outcome. HOWEVER what I did notice was that when I set "Autoresize Subviews" on the container view, it caused different results..but t still seemed to incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this layout issue by executing this code in both ViewWillAppear & ViewWillDisappear. I cannot explain why this works, but I do know that it does.

```
tabBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
tabBar.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
tabBar.superview?.layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might need to put the `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` call at the top of your override. Have you tried that? I would think that the superclass method actually also adjusts the position so your change might be getting overwritten.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work either.